# Load a shared library into a program being debugged in GDB

Tags: gdb

I know there is a similar question, but the program there is started in GDB, so the solution of LD_PRELOAD works. But I want to load a .so in an already running process that I attached to with "-p pid". Should I use mmap or is there a better solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I use mmap

You didn't say *why* you want to load this `.so` (http://xyproblem.info). Assuming you want to call a function from that `.so` after you loaded it, `mmap` will *not* allow you to do that -- the loader will not know anything about that library, will not resolve any symbols in it, etc. etc.

> or is there a better solution ?

This: `(gdb) call dlopen("foo.so", 1)` should work, but I haven't tried it.

Comment: Looks like it is working